# CSS não está sendo carregado

Tags: html, css, cakephp

Tenho o site de um cliente `http://suprimark.com.br/` ele estava funcionando normalmente, mas quando o atendimento da agência foi acessar, ele apareceu assim, sem `css`, sendo que nele tem chamadas para os arquivos `.css`. Eu não tenho ideia do que seja, mas tentei acessar o arquivo do css pela URL e fala que não foi encontrado, mas o mesmo se encontra na pasta sim, `webroot` do CakePHP. O erro que da é **404**

**public_html/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
#    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
 #   RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**public_html/app/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**public_html/app/webroot/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Verifica a configuração de permissão de pasta. Você colocou os arquivos nas pastas `webroot/css/` ? ativo no servidor o mod-rewrite ?coloca ae seu código.

Comment: Como está a configuração do `mod_rewrite`? o Erro é 404 ou 403?

Comment: O erro é 404. Postei os arquivos .htaccess

Comment: qual diretorio exatamente está o css? (exemplo: webroot/css/home/estilo.css)

Comment: public_html/app/webroot/css/main.css, etc.

Comment: Os arquivos css estão disponível dentro da pasta app em `http://suprimark.com.br/app/css/main.css`

Comment: como faço para alterar para pegar da webroot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

descomente

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```